# How to access downloads folder in internal memory in windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I want to access downloaded files in Downloads folder which is available in internal memory. I tried C:\Data\Users\Public\Downloads\ it gives an unauthorized result. How to have access to internal memory in windows phone 8.1.

Comment: Is this a Silverlight, or Universal app? Could you include your code for attempting to open the file?

Comment: Its windows phone 8.1 App

Comment: Windows Phone 8.1 supports two types of app; those based on Silverlight, and Universal apps (based on RT). Each have differing APIs, so it would be useful to say which you're using, or include your code that's not working for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a file or folder picker

```
 FileOpenPicker picker= new FileOpenPicker();
 openPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Downloads;
 StorageFile file = await piker.PickSingleFileAsync();
```

or

```
 FolderPicker piker= new FolderPicker();
 piker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Downloads;
 piker.PickFolderAndContinue();
```

Comment: How can i get the list of files in downloads folder using FolderPicker?

Comment: c# code in the app can't get access to the downloaded files. the only way to get downloaded files is through picker. for selecting multiple files you can you use PickMultipleFilesAndContinue method

Comment: Can you please share some code snippets on PickMultipleFilesAndContinue ?